# Spring-API design parentid missing in child controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using spring boot for designing API.

I am implementing following API design in the spring-boot.

1. localhost:8989//parent.
2. localhost:8989//parent/parentid
3. localhost:8989//parent/parentid/child

Following controller, I have implemented.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(
 path="/parent",
 consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
 produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public class ParentController {
         @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
         public @ResponseBody ResponseObject getAllParent() {
            //code to return all parent
         }      
         @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, path="{id}")
         public @ResponseBody ResponseObject getParent(@PathVariable("id") 
                                               Integer parentid) {
              //code to return specific parent
         }
         @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, path="{id}/child")
         public @ResponseBody ResponseObject getParentChild 
                                    (@PathVariable("id")Integer parentid) {
              //code to return specific parent
         }
  }
```

Here i am requesting with below request.

1. localhost:8989//parent ->works fine
2. localhost:8989//parent/parentid ->works fine
3. localhost:8989//parent/parentid/child-> Not working properly. Getting below error.

   {
       "timestamp": "2018-09-09T09:44:05.922+0000",
       "status": 500,
       "error": "Internal Server Error",
       "message": "Missing URI template variable 'parentid' for method parameter of type Integer",
       "path": "/parent/1536485852/child/"
   }

Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change this method ;

```
 @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value = "{id}/child")
         public @ResponseBody ResponseObject getParentChild 
                                    (@PathVariable("id")Integer parentid) {
              //code to return specific parent
         }
```

Here `path="{id}/child"` is wrong. Add slash starting of this. so this will be like this ;

```
value="/{id}/child"
```

If you dont add slash here, it will concatenate both path. So one of this `"parent"` and other one is `"{id}/child"` . So id is not known. Concatenate both, result will be like `"parentid/child"`. In your exception `parentid` not found. Your path url is not like your wants. In shortly add slash here.

Comment: I'm glad to help you :)